# Htaccess Redirect all files to one specific file on the same domain

Tags: .htaccess

I want to make my site inaccessible and redirect all users to a coming soon page on the same domain, something like this:

www.mysite.com/* redirects to www.mysite.com/coming-soon.php

How do I do this in the .htaccess file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/coming-soon\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com/coming-soon.php [R=307,L]
```

if you want to restrict website access to your machine only add the following condition (replace 111.1.11.11 with you ip address)

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.1\.11\.11$
```

if you want to allow access to some file types (images) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/coming-soon\.php$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|png|gif)$
RewriteRule (.*) http://mysite.com/coming-soon.php [R=307,L]
```

Comment: I've added that, with the domain changes, but I'm getting a 500 Internal error...

Any ideas?

Comment: That brilliant, thanks. Is there any way I can allow exceptions so the coming-soon.php file can show images from the images dir?